# In a Chrome Extension, How can I change the shown url without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, redirect

I am creating a chrome extension that modifies the url for certain pages. I know I can use

`chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: newURL})`

to redirect to another url entirely, but is there a way I can change the visible url without chrome actually going to that page?

(I'm using a proxy server to get to certain pages, and it'd be nicer to look at if I didn't have to see the proxy's url in the omnibox, just the actual site I'm viewing.)

Comment: You mean you'd like someone to be able to show (for example) `http://yourbank.com` instead of `http://myproxy.com`?

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, that's what I mean.